Do sockets continue to be flagged as readable to indicate TCP errors after the peer gracefully closed the connection?
In normal network communication, we are constantly in a blocking recv() call. If an error happens, this recv() will return with an error, and we can immediately abort all processing for the peer.
After the peer has closed the connection and recv() has returned 0, recv() will no longer be called. But our side may still have things to process, and data to be sent. If the other side now forcefully closes the connection with a RST, is there a way to detect it in a timely manner?
For example, will the socket continue to be flagged readable when an error occurs? When that happens, how can I retrieve that error? Can I use select()/epoll()/IOCP to wait the socket to become readable, then call recv(), which will fail, and then get the error?
One scenario when something like this can happen is when an HTTP client sends a request, then shuts down the socket, but instead of waiting for the response, it sends RST and leaves. So the server should have a way to detect this and abort all processing for this client.

When what error occurs? The connection is closed.  No more data, no more errors, nothing. It will continue to be flagged as readable for that reason. But when you got the zero you should have closed the socket and stopped selecting on it at all.

@user207421: the OP is not asking about connection closed in both direction but only a (one-sided) shutdown by the client, i.e. signal that no more data will be send but that data can still be received by the client. This will result in recv returning 0 in the server but the server might still write data to the client, i.e. connection still half-open. If now the client closes the socket (i.e. fully close now) without reading all data from the server a RST will be sent to the server. And the OP asks how to detect this.

I've rewritten the question to be more clear.

The synchronous server code could be peppered select.select calls, looking only for exceptions. But I think it would be more common for the server to be written in some async way (traditionally with nonblocking sockets and select or one if its friends). It'll likely find out about it on its next send call anyway. The server's tasks would need to be implemented in some cancelable way for this to be useful.

@SteffenUllrich I disagree. OP stated HTTP, which doesn’t have half closes.

I think the question could use a bit more clarification - in that first paragraph, is it the client or the server?

@OP If you have something to write, write it, and you will get the error that way. If you get EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK from the write, that’s the time to get select() involved, and yes it will detect the RST, but I believe not as a readable but a writeable condition, or possibly an error condition.

And a client that sends a request and then shuts down the socket is not speaking valid HTTP. You are quite entitled to just close your socket and just forget about it.

@tdelaney We are server. Because servers normally does not close the connection first, to avoid ports getting stuck in TIME_WAIT state. But really the question applies to peer to peer too, where the other end closes first.

@SteffenUllrich A HTTP client can shutdown the writing end of their socket, right after sending the request, and still wait for the response, before fully closing the socket. A server need to be prepared for this.

@SteffenUllrich And that's the issue, we have nothing to send until the server has finished processing. But even if we have something to send during processing, an error can still happen between two send()-s.
The actual protocol we are implementing is ICAP. And we are implementing it for virus-scanning, so the processing can take significant time before the server responds.

I don't see that any of this makes any difference. If you aren't using select(), just do the sends() you need until you either finish them or get an error, then close() the socket. I'm not at all clear what it is you are actually asking, now that you've taken select() out of it.

@Calmarius: I'm not sure that what you want will help in case of your scenario (ICAP server). A client will usually only send a RST after the half-close, if there were still unread data  in the clients receive buffer at the moment of close. But if your server has never send any data to the client (i.e. still waiting for end of analysis) then client will not send the RST. Also, an ICAP client should not do a half-close after sending the request.

What you seem to be asking for now is the ability to predict the future: ‘will the next send() fail?’ TCP isn’t like that, and neither is life.

@user207421 If the peer have sent RST, then the TCP stack knows about the failure. I want to catch those cases. I can also have TCP keepalive configured with a short timeout and repeat interval to allow the TCP stack detect if the peer is unresponsive.

Sigh. You will catch those cases when you do the send. I’ve already stated that. Or else the send will succeed. What is your question?

@user207421: The point is to detect the RST right when it was send by the client, so that one can stop the current extensive processing (malware scanning) since the client will not need the result anyway. Only detecting this when sending the response after analysis is done wastes many resources.

@SteffenUllrich Then he needs to restore select() to his question, which he removed hours ago, and use it as I indicated in my comment above, also hours ago.

@user207421 I added back the select() part. I thought it was clear from the "flagged as readable" part. Since there are quite a few APIs to check if the socket is readable: select, poll, epoll, kqueue on Unix-likes or whatever that's awailable on Windows.

OK let’s state one thing. ‘After the peer has closed the connection and recv() has returned 0’ it is impossible for the peer to then ‘forcefully close the connection with an RST’.  It’s already closed. Period.  These are your words, not an interpretation. Your question is about a situation that does not and cannot exist. What can happen is that the peer’s TCP stack sends you an RST if you send something to such a connection. In which case, as I’ve already stated, your question consists of trying to foretell the future.

For completeness, it also cannot happen after a shutdown for output. The connection has already been closed with a FIN so no RST can be issued by the application. I have tested this. You are bending over backwards to compensate for an imaginary rogue client that cannot behave as you describe.

@user207421 Both sides need to send a FIN to completely close a TCP connection.
Peer sends a request, then sends FIN. Then our side processes the request, then responds after a minute, but during the meantime the peer is gone, the TCP stack on their side does not recognize our packets and responds with RST. Our side has tcp keepalive enabled with short timeout and interval, so our side regularly sends keepalive packets (that's the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option) to check if the peer is still there. If the peer is still listening those packets are ACK-ed, if the peer is gone, we'll get an RST.

So you have already responded, which is the second case I addressed. So what’s the problem?

Regarding the "retrieving the error" part of your question, epoll/poll allow you to capture various events on the descriptors they are monitoring.
For data arriving you would get a (E)POLLIN, but there are others maskable events for errors, as well as for socket-specific concepts like hang-up and disconnection.
Take a look at the man7 pages, specifically the way that POLLHUP and POLLRDHUP might help you here.

All true, however there will be no events other than 'readable' in the scenario described by the OP.
